# Using bash redirection with input variables to script

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to run a script on a remote host via ssh. The script requires input. I'm trying to avoid scp'ing the file to the host to run it. Here is what I have so far, but it is not working:

```
ssh -T root@host < ./my_script my_input
```

I'm getting error output:

```
./my_script my_input: No such file or directory
```

Running ./my_script my_input works fine if I scp the script to the host and run it, but I would like to avoid the scp process.

Comment: you are trying to execute the my_script my_input from the host to your pc.
swith your comman as : 

./my_script my_input > ssh -T root@host

Comment: @angel, your example would re-direct the output from my_script to a file named "ssh" which isn't what I'm looking to accomplish.

Comment: you're right, i forgot that.if you use a pipe to re-direct? 
./my_script my_input | ssh -T root@host

Comment: @angel I'm trying to run the contents of my_scrip on the remote server and I want to pass the input my_input to my_script. If I do not try to pass input to my_script, my example works. But when I add my_input per my example it does not work and gives the error message in the original post.

Comment: ssh -T root@host < ./my_script "my_input"

Comment: Is there any reason you cant ssh inside the script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add "bash -s" to saying at the server than we will execute the bash script.

```
ssh root@host "bash -s" < ./my_script.sh "my_input"
```

Comment: not, but i asked to a friend who know this and he said that : 

ssh serverA "bash -s" < ./ex.bash "hi" "bye"
--> hi bye

Comment: Needs a space after ./my_script.sh otherwise it tries to execute a file called ./my_script.shmy_input